# Azure Active directory authentication to website hosted on Azure VM's IIS

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-app-service-plans, azure-webapps, azure-vm

I have an hosted a website in IIS on-premise on win2008 and is configured for windows authentication.

Now I want to migrate this to Cloud using lift and shift (IaaS).

I know we can easily migrate to azure app service ,but I don't want to migrate to Azure App Service ...  I want to migrate this to azure using Lift and Shift approach.

Now on my azure VM , I have installed IIS and configured same website in IIS, but how do I configure Azure Active Directory authentication for this. Please help

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between adding Azure AD authentication to an App Service, or an IaaS hosted app, follow the tutorials of microsoft which these steps:

- (setup Azure AD)
- Add middleware, pages and controller
- Register the Application in Azure AD

The following is just a random example I found by googling:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp